# Unable to change properties of ListView FMX except by Text

Tags: listview, delphi, firemonkey, listviewitem

I created a ListView and add some ItemsText's, arranged them in their respective sizes/positions and when try to populate them, some ItemsText was cut in half (short width), then I decide to change all of them with `OnUpdatingObjects` Event using `Canvas.TextWidth` on Text and adding more 10p in width to be sure.

My Vars ( `AItem` comes in `OnUpdatingObjects` Event which is `TListViewItem`):

```
 var
   Drawable : TListItemText;
   Text : String;
   i : integer;
begin
   for i := 0 to AItem.Objects.Count-1 do begin
      if AItem.View.Drawables[i].ClassName = 'TListItemText' then begin
         Drawable := TlistItemText(AItem.Objects.Drawables[i]);
         Text := Drawable.Text;

         Drawable.Width := Round(Canvas.TextWidth(Text))+10;
      end;
   end;
end;
```

The width doesn't change and if I do manually like :

```
TListItemText(Objects.FindDrawable('MyText')).Width := 200;
```

Doesn't change too.

Already try a lot of different ways to do it, but none of them worked.

**PS** : The Listview is in DynamicAppearance.

**PS.2** : The Drawable variable shows the new value in Width but no changes on ListView, except by the Text Property none of them are changeable.

Answer (score 0):

try using onUpdateObjects

```
procedure TFHistory.lvMainUpdateObjects(const Sender: TObject;
  const AItem: TListViewItem);
var
  AText : TListItemText;
begin
  AText := AItem.View.FindDrawable('kd') as TListItemText;
  AText.Width := 20;
end;
```

Comment: AText its coming `nil`

Comment: change 'kd' with component name @Geovanii

Answer (score 0):

I was a little curious, so I try this with success

```
procedure TForm2.ListView1UpdateObjects(const Sender: TObject;
  const AItem: TListViewItem);
begin
AItem.Objects.FindDrawable('Text2').Width :=Round(Canvas.TextWidth(AItem.Objects.FindObject('Text2').Data.AsString))+5;
end;
```

Comment: Idk why but somehow accuses `AV` and Inside `TextWidth` come with `Inaccessible Value` using just your code triggered `AV`, my guess it would be the FMX itself with ListView properties crashing